# pending approvals

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

A couple of times recently, I approved edits and found that they still need approval from one other person.  During the interval, I can't do any other edits to the posting!

When does an edit have to be approved by more than one person, and when is one enough?

Is there any way around the restriction I mention at the end of my first paragraph above?

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6535/so-much-approval-required-for-edits

Comment: Another similar question: [Editing now completely blocked while an edit is pending](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6480/editing-now-completely-blocked-while-an-edit-is-pending?lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Improving the edit approves it directly.

My method is to examine the edit closely and be sure that I don't want to change things further. If I do want to edit, I just improve instead of approve, and it gets through immediately.

---

**Proof:** https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/29517

Comment: I would also suggest that we could later delete the comments here and document the whole experiment in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6485), so that this is not polluted with too many comments.

Comment: SO is sometimes treated differently because the number of users is so much higher (another example is that migration requires more votes at SO).  My understanding is that as other sites grow they will get some of these minor changes.

Comment: Yes, I have. Perhaps we could clean up the above comments. I leave here only the relevant meta.SO link [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) where it is mentioned that: *The revised text is published when the improver saves their changes.* (I should have read that thread more carefully when I posted this link for the first time.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that anyone can edit a question until a pending edit is either accepted or denied. Before a pending edit is either accepted or denied, another change to the post might cause an irreconcilably conflicting edit. I don't see any way to get around this restriction.  Find another user to accept or deny the edit.